# Are 汚い and いやらしい the same?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, i-adjectives

Is one exclusively for actual dirty while one is for just the feeling of dirtiness, e.g. talking to a lewd pervert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

汚い is the most straightforward translation of "dirty". It's used both literally (e.g., 汚い文字, 汚い服, 汚いトイレ) and figuratively (e.g., 汚い言葉, 汚い犯罪, 汚い組織). It rarely has a sexual connotation. 汚い本 usually refers to a book covered with mud, for example.

When いやらしい modifies a tangible object, it means "lewd". いやらしい本/映画 usually refers to porn books/movies. But it's more commonly used to describe someone's indecent, disgusting, sarcastic or filthy behavior. いやらしい言葉 may or may not have sexual connotations depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

「汚い」と「いやらしい」という単純な形容詞を質問者がなぜ辞書で調べずに、このサイトにわざわざ質問するのか疑問に感じました。

直感ですが、「物理的」か「感覚的/感じ方」かというレベルの違いでなく、**「汚い」と「いやらしい」とは基本的に違います**。

Jisho.orgではどのように定義しているのか調べてみました。

> #### [汚｛きたな｝い](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%B1%9A%E3%81%84)
>
> I-adjective
>   1. **dirty**; <del>**filthy**</del>; foul; unclean
>   2. disordered; messy; untidy; poor (e.g. handwriting)​
>   3. **indecent** (language<del>, etc.</del>); <del>**dirty**</del>; vulgar; coarse
>   4. dastardly; mean; base; underhanded
>   5. stingy; greedy​

日本語で「汚い」とはどういう時に使うかをjisho.orgの定義の番号に沿って考えると次のようになります。

> １．泥で汚れて服が**汚い**。何日もお風呂に入っていないので顔や体が**汚い**。掃除をしていないのでホコリやゴミで部屋が**汚い**。
>   ２．部屋の整理整頓をしていないあるいは片付けていないので**汚い**。あいつは字が**汚い**（＝字が下手｛へた｝だ）。**汚**い字だね（＝下手な字だね）。
>   ３．育ちが悪いのか、友達が悪いのか、あいつは言葉[遣]{づか}いが**汚い**。
>   ４．後ろから撃つなど遣｛や｝り方が**汚い**、もっと正々堂々と正面から勝負しろ。フェアでない。
>   ５．レジの金に手をつけるなど、**汚い**ことをしているらしい。人が見ていないとズルをする**汚い**やつだ。例えば、（ゴルフで）ラフに入ったボールを足で打ちやすい方に蹴{け}り出したり、１打ごまかすなど、あいつは、いつも**汚い**ことをしている。

**結論として、「汚い」は、jisho.orgの定義どおりで問題ないと思います。**

同様に「嫌らしい」をjisho.orgで調べると次のようになります。

> #### [嫌｛いや｝らしい](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%84%E3%82%84%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%84)
>
> I-adjective
>   1. disgusting; <del>**filthy**</del>; repulsive; detestable; unpleasant; disagreeable
>   2. lewd; lascivious; <del>**indecent**</del>; obscene; <del>**filthy**</del>; <del>**dirty**​</del>

「嫌らしい」にも「汚い」にも、"indecent"と"filthy"と"dirty"とが入っているので、英語で理解すると混乱しそうですね。
「汚い」と「嫌らしい」の違いを明確にするために、両方の単語のjisho.orgの定義から、消しても問題が起きないと思われる部分に**取り消し線** (**strike-through**)を入れました。これで両者の違いがはっきりしたのではないでしょうか。

> #### 重要
>
> jisho.orgの説明になく、私が重要だと感じた「嫌らしい」に付け加えるべき説明として、1の意味でも2の意味でも、日本語では圧倒的に**女性が男性に対して使う形容詞**だということです。「**あの人いやらしい！**」と言えば、ほとんどの場合これは**女性の発言**です。

Comment: 「あの人いやらしい！」の発言者がほとんどの場合女性であるとすれば、その理由は「あの人いやらしい！」という全体の言葉遣いが女性的であるためであって、「嫌らしい」という形容詞に帰するべきものではないと思います。単語自体に「女性が男性に対して」という傾向や制約らしきものがあるとは考えにくいです。「あいついやらしい奴だな」が男性による、男性もしくは女性に対しての言葉であることに何ら性別上の違和は認められませんし、男性による「あいついやらしい奴だな」が女性による「あの人いやらしい！」と比較して実際の使用頻度が大きく異なるとも思えません。

Comment: @goldbrick: コメントありがとうございます。「いやらしい」には１と２の２つの意味があります。意味上の使用頻度は調べておりませんが、２の意味で使う場合が多いと私は思っております。１は使用頻度が５０対５０かも知れませんが、２は圧倒的に女性が使うことが多い形容詞だと思っております。結果として「あの人」という表現を除いても総合的に女性が使用する頻度が高いと思いますがいかがですか。「いやらしい！」という言葉は女性語です。何なら、街頭でアンケートを取ってみたいです。

Comment: @goldbrick:「いやらしい」の同義語、類義語を調べるとたくさんあります。１の意味、２の意味でどのような表現を使うかと見ますと、私には「いけ好かない」「いやらしい」は掛け値なしに男性があまり使わないと思います。逆に言うと、絶対にとは言いませんが、男性は女性に比べてこの表にある別の表現を使うように思います。http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%84%E3%82%84%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%84

Comment: 語彙的には「いやらしい」という形容詞のみから成る「いやらしい！」は”発話”であって”形容詞”ではありません。したがって、女性的なのは「いやらしい！」という発言であって、「いやらしい」という形容詞ではありません。（「あの人いやらしい！」も同様です。）「いやらしい」という単語は、たとえ性的な意味の方に限っても、使用者や対象者の男性女性の区別なく使用できると思います。試しにグーグルで「いやらしい」を検索してみると「女性が男性に対して」という制限を示唆する結果にはなりませんでした。ざっと見たところ「女性→男性」のケースはそれ以外のケースより少数です。ちなみに「いやらしい男」と「いやらしい女」はだいだい同じぐらいのヒット数でした。